# Change package manager application info meta data in android

Tags: android, metadata, android-package-managers

I would like to change the value of a meta-data in the AndroidManifest.xml file :

I am using the following code :

```
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(
                activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
applicationInfo.metaData.putString("dataName", "2");
```

But the applicationInfo is not saved into the package manager. When packageManager.getApplicationInfo() is called afterwards, I get the old value.

I didn't see a setApplicationInfo() method, how can I proceed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the applicationInfo that getApplicationInfo returns is always a copy and there are no apis to change metadata

Answer (score 2):

This meta data can be only supplied from Manifest file and can not be changed after that(as pointed above it will always return a copy and even if update it in some component it will not get updated originally)